# Get indices of elements in a list that do not contain any NA

Tags: r, list, na

I have a list of vectors with varying lengths, some with numbers and some with NA. I want to get the indices of the list that do not have any NA.

```
m <- list(3, NA, c(NA, NA, NA), c(4,5), c(3, NA))
```

When I use `is.na` it still returns indices 3 and 5, even though the vectors contain NA.

```
which((!is.na(m)), TRUE)
[1] 1 3 4 5
```

I would like to only return indices 1 and 4. How do I do this?

Comment: @MrFlick hard to find a direct duplicate, maybe post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to iterate over the vectors in your list is with `sapply`. And then you can use `anyNA` to check if there are any NA values. Then negate that so you only find those that don't have NA values. You can do that all with

```
which(!sapply(m, anyNA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate`

```
with(aggregate(cbind(values = !is.na(values)) ~ ind, 
       stack(setNames(m, seq_along(m))), FUN = all), ind[values])
```